# Can I compare only file contents?

Tags: winmerge

I want to compare two folders, each having about 5-6 thousands files and folders. Among these probably 0.1% would be actually different but WinMerge first shows all files saying "text files are different" and when I open these files one by one it opens a dialog saying contents in both files are the same. It is nearly impossible for me to find files actually having different text, in this way.
First, I tried to set options but no success.
Then, I thought this initial difference may be due to different time stamps. So I made all file time stamps (create, last modified and last accessed ) exactly the same but the result is the still same.
Am I missing something? Or is there any way to filter the list so that I may see only the files with some difference? Or any other idea?

Comment: Are you ignoring white space when viewing each file?

Comment: YES, I am ignoring both white spaces and different line feeds

Comment: Try [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

Comment: For anyone still finding this question and still needing an answer, pls see the answer from @dog44wgm below, who suggests simply upgrading to a newer version of Winmerge.

Answer (score 14):

I would have thought that WinMerge with the following settings would work:

[image]

If it doesn't, I would ask the question in their [forums](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=113216&group_id=13216&func=browse).
I believe this is worth the effort, as WinMerge is my best file-compare product.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Compare option "Ignore carriage return differences".

Differences in line endings (CRLF/CR/LF) are the usual suspect when one mode of comparison (binary) reports differences but another mode (text) claims that the files are the same.

Comment: Its already like this.

Comment: You are right @brian, there is really a line feed difference in most of the files that winmerge is not ignoring in first pass.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the software called '**Beyond Compare**'.

Comment: its not free...

Comment: Seems to be a good one, but I had to change a few settings (essentially, removing the quick compare rules on *file size* & *timestamp*) to avoid having the "not so different files" highlit in my compare.  The fact that it's non-free isn't that much of a problem, since a 30 days trial is available (and this soft is probably worth the few bucks it costs), but it raises a few uncertainties about the available functionnalities if one isn't intending to spend money on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with WinMerge 2.14. So I tried **WinMerge 2.16.2**, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [ECMerge](http://www.elliecomputing.com) or Araxis as well. They both have appropriate settings to ignore spaces / CRLF.